# Where can I obtain a comprehensive list of all languages spoken in Papua New Guinea by province?

Tags: list-of-languages

I need a list of languages spoken in Papua New Guinea mentioned alongside the province/district/LLG they are spoken in along with the number of speakers. Where can I obtain such a list for free?

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists, there are too many languages (>1000, and in many language families) and more being found on a regular basis. And there are nowhere near enough linguists documenting the languages of PNG for us to even have a good sample across all families. There is a [database of PNG languages here](http://transnewguinea.org). Also you could look at Bill Palmer's recent volume to get an overview of the region: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110295252/html

Comment: Plus, most people are polyglot and the boundary between Indonesia and PNG is a straight line on a map of a mountainous island. Imagine how accurate any such list would be. The Australian National University has been studying NG languages since long before PNG was a country. That's the place to start looking. Senior Linguistics Department. Professor Wurm.